# Writing to a file when python prints

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I'm making a bot with discord.py and need a logging system, my bot already outputs errors to a log file, however I would like it to output anything printed to console into a text file.

E.g:

[This is being printed to the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz08A.png)

[And I want it to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1jKj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this link

```
with open("file","a") as f:
   #place all your codes in this block
    print("hello",file=f)
```